# Extracting application insight instrumentationkey based on name

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to configure some automation for a large cloud service that requires many different instances of application insight. Is there a way to extract instrumentation key based on application insight name? Through some management library perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is .net library for that.

First, install the following nuget packages in your project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights -IncludePrerelease
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication -IncludePrerelease
```

Then, write a method which return the instrumentation key based on app insights name.

```
        static string GetIKey(string app_insights_name)
        {
            string IKey = "";
            var auth = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

            const string url = "https://management.azure.com/";

            string token = auth.GetAccessTokenAsync(url).Result;

            var cred = new TokenCredentials(token);

            var client = new ApplicationInsightsManagementClient(cred)
            {
                //replace with your subscription id
                SubscriptionId = "your-subscription-id",
            };

            var list = new List<ApplicationInsightsComponent>();

            var all = client.Components.List();
            list.AddRange(all);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.Name.ToLower() == app_insights_name.ToLower())
                {
                    return item.InstrumentationKey;
                }

            }

            //if no app insights name matches, return ""
            return "";

        }
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: @HåvardL, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks. If you don't know how to mark, please refer to this [article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top), thanks :).

Comment: are you familiar with how to extract it in a production environment? Is there some additional setup for this to work?